# C# ListView control MouseDown and MouseUp events for ColumnHeader

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am trying to catch the MouseDown and MouseUp events in a listview's column header, to make the parent form movable via insider listview's header.

I could actually achieve this overriding the WndPrc but it only works within the listview area, not the columnheader. While the idea of moving a form via it's insider listview's header can be good (since my listview is not sortable by column click), moving the form from anywhere inside the listview is definetely not. It will cause to move on every item click which can be very disturbing.

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/header-controls) says we can create a custom header control for a list/listview control but I could not find an example for C#/VB.Net despite all my search.

Anyone knows how to implement this or have an example ?

Thanks a lot by now.

Comment: What's wrong with the default way of moving a form, used by millions of people every hour, wherein one drags the title bar of the form? I've never looked at a listview column header and thought "that doesn't look clickable, I bet I can drag the whole form using it" - a very strange UI experience you're creating ?!

Comment: It is hard to do because the column header is a window by itself.  Getting the handle to that window and registering a mouse event for it completely not covered by Winforms.  You need to send the LVM_GETHEADER message to get the handle, wrap it with NativeWindow derived class and override its WndProc() method to get the mouse notification.

Comment: @CaiusJard Parent form border is none. It's a borderless window (it must be to save space, in case you are to question that too)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was very simple. 
I share the code that I developed in case anyone will ever need this.

```
public class lw : ListView

{

    const int LVM_FIRST = 0x1000;
    const int LVM_GETHEADER = (LVM_FIRST + 31);

    ListViewColumnHeaderWindow Header;

    public lw()
    {

        //add 3 items for experiment
        ListViewItem lwItem = new ListViewItem("a");
        lwItem.SubItems.Add("b");
        lwItem.SubItems.Add("c");
        Items.Add(lwItem);

        lwItem = new ListViewItem("d");
        lwItem.SubItems.Add("e");
        lwItem.SubItems.Add("f");
        Items.Add(lwItem);

        lwItem = new ListViewItem("g");
        lwItem.SubItems.Add("h");
        lwItem.SubItems.Add("i");
        Items.Add(lwItem);

    }


    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        //here we need to wrap the header window to listen it's WndProc messages
        IntPtr hHeader = (IntPtr)SendMessage(Handle, LVM_GETHEADER, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        Console.WriteLine("Creating ListViewColumnHeaderWindow for LVM_GETHEADER IntPtr {0}", hHeader);
        Header = new ListViewColumnHeaderWindow(hHeader, this);
    }

    public void OnColumnMouseDown(object state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Header.MouseDown @{0}", (Point)state);
        //now I can start to move the form from this point...
    }

    public void OnColumnMouseUp()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Header.MouseUp");
    }


    public void MoveFromHeader(Point p) {
        Console.WriteLine("Mouse moved to @{0}", p);
    }
}


class ListViewColumnHeaderWindow : NativeWindow
{

    lw Parent;

    bool MouseIsDown;

    System.Threading.Timer MTIMER;

    public ListViewColumnHeaderWindow(IntPtr hHeader, lw parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;
        MouseIsDown = false;
        AssignHandle(hHeader);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (MouseIsDown && m.Msg == 4608)
        {
            //this message is being sent when user starts to RESIZE 
            //the column header by clicking the column resizer. 
            //We should immediately cancel the mousedown event 
            //to allow user to resize the column (instead of moving the form)
            MouseIsDown = false;
            MTIMER?.Dispose();
        }

        switch (msg)
        {
            case 513: // WM_LBUTTONDOWN

                MouseIsDown = true;
                //due to possible column header resizing,
                //I don't call OnColumnMouseDown event immediately here,
                //but set a delay to detect the message '4608' 
                //which is being sent right after WM_LBUTTONDOWN
                //that indicates the mouse is down to column resizing.
                MTIMER?.Dispose();
                MTIMER = new System.Threading.Timer(Parent.OnColumnMouseDown, new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32()), 200, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
                break;

            case 512: // WM_MOUSEMOVE

                if (MouseIsDown)                    
                    Parent.MoveFromHeader(new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32()));                    
                break;

            case 514: // WM_LBUTTONUP

                if (MouseIsDown)
                {
                    MouseIsDown = false;
                    Parent.OnColumnMouseUp();
                }
                break;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);

    }
}
```